# interpretation coefficient sign dynamic model

Tags: autoregressive, dynamic-regression

[image]

Screenshot of a paper under a section about dynamic interpretations.
Source: https://doi.org/10.3200/JECE.36.1.77-92

Does anyone care to explain this to me. Are they stating that the negative coefficient of Xt-1 does not imply a negative relationship?

If so, would it be correct to interpret a positive xt-1 being due to the long-run impact of x being greater than the short-run impact?